# Смертная казнь: грамотно ли это?

Tags: плеоназм

Понятие "смертная казнь" широко распространено. Но, если вдуматься, а не плеоназм ли это? Есть казнь, то ясно, что она смертная. Или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Не плеоназм. Вспомните "семь казней египетских".
"Казнь" исходно равносильно назаканию, ну может - более суровому, физическому наказанию. 
Непосредственно с лишением жизни стало ассоциироваться только с отмиранием других видов физического наказания: нанесением увечий, порки и проч. 
В современном языке исходное значение казни малоупотребительно, не исчезло окончательно. Уже это оправдывает сочетание "смертная казнь". Ну и традиция, конечно -  великая вещь.
Есть и еще один момент. "Смертная казнь" - название всех видов казни: через повшение, расстрел и проч. В юридическом языке оно означало, что конкретный вид казни в приговоре не обговаривается, и решается на основании общих норм и/или местных традиций. Вплоть до выбора способа приговоренным. При формулировках, указывающий способ экзекуции ("казнь через повешение", расстрел, инъекция, гильотина и проч.) слово "смертная" обычно не используются. 
А вообще очень надеюсь, что само понятие скоро станет исключительно достоянием Истории.

Comment: Уточнение: не семь, а десять казней египетских.